# How to use connect in Qt to know when the "X" (exit) button is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, button, qt5

I'm struggling in figuring out how to use the connect function to recognize when the "x" button at the top left corner has been clicked. The red "x" button that cancels the window.

[image]

I know that I can override the closeEvent to do whatever I want but i need to use the connect function. Let me give you a background of the problem.

I have a function that I am calling from main like this:

```
ManageEmployeeWindow mng;
int choice = mng.checkChoice();
```

checkChoice is used to create the window and return an int depending on what button on that window that the user decides to click.

ex- If the user clicks button 1 then the checkChoice will return 1.

Now knowing that I would like to return a number through checkChoice using the connect function to recognize when the button is clicked, how can i do this when the "x" button is clicked?. Is there anyway of doing that?

Btw here is checkChoice just so you can understand what I mean with the connect.

```
int ManageEmployeeWindow::checkChoice(){

this->exec();
cout << "Inside of the checkChoice" << endl;
QEventLoop waitForResponse;
connect(ui->ManualEmployeeUpdate, SIGNAL (clicked()), &waitForResponse, SLOT(quit()));

connect(ui->DataIntegrationTool, SIGNAL (clicked()), &waitForResponse, SLOT(quit()));

connect(x,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(ButtonPressed()));

waitForResponse.exec();

return choice;

}
```

Please let me hear your thoughts on this.

Thank you and my apoligies if I handed out too much detail

Comment: In the meantime, if anyone responds within the next half hour please keep in mind that i will be on the road. I will respond as soon as I can. which should be in half an hour

Comment: Could you explain yourself better?

Comment: What you want is a signal that tells you when the x button is pressed ?, if you press that button closes the window or not?

Comment: What if they use a keyboard shortcut instead of clicking the x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a signal when you press the X button you can create the signal and emit it in the `closeEvent` method.

```
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event){
        emit clicked();
        event->ignore();
    }

signals:
    void clicked();
```

Comment: Ok i understand what you're saying. But usually doesn't the connect button take in connect(button name, signal, slot). what would the button name be?

Comment: There is no name or signal associated with that button.

Comment: Ok so could you please explain what would I pass in connect(). What would i pass in?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm still trying to get started in Qt

Comment: The connection is like any signal: `connect({sender}, SIGNAL(cliked()), {receiver}, SLOT({slot receiver}));`

Comment: Ok so what would be the sender in this case? And would it look something like this:

Comment: connect(sender, SIGNAL(clicked), reciever, SLOT(quit()));

Comment: where the clicked signal is from the close event

Comment: If you are connecting it inside the same widget would be the same bone `this`

Comment: `connect(this, SIGNAL(cliked()), {receiver}, SLOT({slot receiver}));`

Comment: So i'm receiving an erro tellimg me that clicked was not defined in this scope. Its when I emit clicked(); . Do you know why that is?

Comment: Have you added the signal statement in the header?

Comment: ooopppps I didnt define it as a signal. My bad